# Proving the function is holomorphic and jumping

Tags: complex-analysis

This is the problem 5 in chaper 3 in Stein-Shakarchi's complex analysis.
It states let $g(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-M}^M{\frac{h(x)}{x-z}}{dx}$ where $h$ is continuous and supported in $[-M,M]$

Now, I am trying to show that $g$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}-[-M,M]$. 
It doesn't seem hard, but I am not sure where to start... Do I need to just show how this is differentiable in the range? How?

Also, if I want to say that $g$ vanishes at infinity, is it enough to state that when $z$ goes to infinity, the denominator goes to negative infinity, thus giving the integral of 0?

Lastly, I need to prove the “jump” of $g$ across $[−M,M]$ is $h$, that is,
$h(x) = \lim _{\epsilon\to 0} g (x +\epsilon i)−g(x−\epsilon i)$.
The hint in the book says to express the difference $g(x + \epsilon i)−g(x−\epsilon i)$ in terms of a convolution of $h$ with the Poisson kernel. How can this be done, and how does it prove the problem?

I'm pretty lost in general, and any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: For holomorphic just prove you can differentiate with respect to $z$ under the integral sign, using say Lebesgue dominated convergence.  To show that $g$ vanishes at infinity, do something like $|g(z)|\le \int |h|/(2\pi(|z|-M))$.

Comment: for the last part, $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x-y-\epsilon i} -\frac{1}{x-y+\epsilon i} = \frac{2 \epsilon i}{(x-y)^2 + \epsilon^2}$ and $\displaystyle\int_{-M}^M 2 \epsilon i \frac{h(x)}{(x-y)^2+ \epsilon^2} dx = 2i h \ast P_\epsilon(y)$ with $\displaystyle P_\epsilon(y) = \frac{ \epsilon}{y^2 + \epsilon^2}$. and what is asked is to find that $\displaystyle P_\epsilon(y) = \frac{1}{\epsilon} \frac{1}{(y/\epsilon)^2 + 1}$ whose limit when $\epsilon \to 0$ is one of the possible definitions of the convergence to the Dirac delta